# Open txt file and draw histogram in root

Tags: root-framework

I have a txt file which contains numbers. I want to draw a histogram according to this file in root. But I can't do this.

```
{ 
    TFile *f = new TFile("myfile.root"); 

    f.ls(); 

    TH1F * h1 = (TH1F*)f.Get("h1"); 
    h1->Draw(); 
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure your tag is not correct.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: c++ language I try this: c1 = TCanvas("c1","c1",900,700) than  page was opened but ı cannot my txt file because program said is not a root file

Comment: this post has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475239/ascii-files-in-root/30480533#30480533

Comment: Read the error message you should have seen in your terminal. Your script is completely wrong. Please read the ROOT Users' Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorial from the ROOT website](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/tutorials/tree/basic.C.html). As far as I know ROOT can't open a plain text file directly. The `TFile("myfile.root")` call can be used to open a ROOT file (i.e. a binary file created by ROOT containing persistified ROOT objects such as histograms), which as you point out causes errors if you try to open a plain text file using it. The approach shown in the tutorial page is to create a TH1, then use standard C++ I/O streams to read from your text fiule and fill the histogram in the normal way.