# Drawing graph from a text file by skipping 1st 47 rows in CERN ROOT

Tags: text, graph, root-framework

I am new in root. So sorry if anything very easy.
I cannot call my text file ("Image.txt") in root V 5.34. This text file contains 9 column and 250 rows. I want to read 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 7th (those are separated by "," and have the value from row 47) column as x,y, a, b, z. Then I want to draw graph as y Vs x, b vs a and histogram as count/bin Vs z. Before that I need to grab the value of these column from rows 47. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your kind help. File (Image.txt) as an attachment:
http://www.filedropper.com/image_9

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933112/open-txt-file-and-draw-histogram-in-root and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475239/plotting-ascii-files-in-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE *f = fopen("Image.nap","r");
if (!f) {
  printf("Could not open Image.nap\n");
  return;
}
char line[300];
float v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8;
Int_t i = 0;
TGraph *g = new TGraph();
TGraph *g1 = new TGraph();
TCanvas *c1 = new TCanvas("c1","c1",800,1000);
TH1F *h1=new TH1F ("h1","Elpsarea Histo",100,-400,400);

while (fgets(line,160,f)) {
  if (i>49) {
     sscanf(&line[0]  ,"%g,%g,%g,%g,%g,%g,%g,%g",&v1,&v2,&v3,&v4,&v5,&v6,&v7,&v8);
     g->SetPoint(i,v2,v3);
     g1->SetPoint(i,v5,v6);
     printf ("%g\t", v8);
     h1.Fill(v8);
     }
  i++;
 }
 fclose(f);
 c1->Divide(1,2);
 c1->cd(1);
 g->Draw("AP");

c1.cd(2)
g1.Draw("AP");

TCanvas *c2 = new TCanvas("c2","Histo for Elps area",600,400);
h1->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("Elepse Area Imicron)");
h1->GetYaxis()->SetTitle("Count/bin");
h1->GetXaxis()->CenterTitle();
h1->GetYaxis()->CenterTitle();
h1.Draw();
```

Comment: This is a very "C" way of doing things- best practices in ROOT would have you using `std::string` instead of a fixed size buffer, and smart pointers for the `TGraph`s, which not owned by the directory. As it is now, if this is put as part of a function, it would leak memory pretty badly (particularly if something throws in the middle).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are not looking for someone to provide a complete solution... Let me just briefly outline here a basic idea to get you started.

1. Open the file for reading
2. Loop over the lines in your file and save the line in a string. You can add a counter and skip the lines you don't want to parse.
3. Parse the string for values in individual columns. There are many ways to do that... just search this website.
4. Use the extracted values to add points into a TGraph or fill a TH1

In C++ the code may look like this:

```cpp
std::ifstream myfile("Image.txt");
std::string myline;

while ( std::getline(myfile, myline) )
{
  // Parse the string... E.g.:
  //int d1, d2; float f1;
  //sscanf(line.c_str(), "%d,%f,%d", &d1, &f1, &d2);

  // Use d1, d2, f1 to fill a histogram or whatever...
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear @plexoos.